# Git está permitindo alterar de branch mesmo com alterações sem commit

Tags: git, branch, checkout

Normalmente quando trabalho com git, faço alguma alteração em uma branch e tento dar um checkout para outra sem commitar ele exibe a mensagem:

```
Changes not staged for commit:
  (utilize "git add <arquivo>..." para atualizar o que será submetido)
  (use "git restore <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)
```

Ou algo semelhante...

Porém depois que instalei o git de novo ele não está fazendo mais essa restrição nos projetos. Isso é alguma configuração?
Estou usando git version 2.25.1 no ubuntu

Comment: Certo, não entendi muito bem o erro.
Tu ta conseguindo adicionar os arquivos com **git add**?
Consegue fazer **commit**?
Já tentou fazer um **git init**?

Answer (score 1):

> [...] faço alguma alteração em uma branch [...]

Primeiramente, se você fez essas alterações e não fez nem o `commit` nem o `add`, significa que você não alterou em branch nenhuma. Está apenas no seu diretório local.

Ao trocar de branch o Git verifica se as mudanças contidas nessa troca influenciam arquivos que foram modificados no seu diretório local. Se não influenciar, o checkout é feito sem problemas. Se sim, ele pede para você fazer o commit, stash ou reverter.

A mensagem de erro é a seguinte:

```
$ git checkout master
error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by checkout:
        arquivo.txt
Please commit your changes or stash them before you switch branches.
Aborting
```

Ou, se não tiver problemas ao trocar de branch, a mensagem indica que suas modificações locais foram levadas na troca de branch:

```
$ git checkout master
Switched to branch 'master'
M       arquivo.txt
```

Acredito que embora a mensagem possa ser diferente por entre versões, o comportamento geral é o mesmo.

Para maiores esclarecimentos, leia a [documentação](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout), ou veja [esta resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1304645/10746978) (em inglês).